# Installing QML modules on Fedora

Tags: qt, fedora

I am trying to implement a simple map view in a PySide6 Qt project by linking a QML file.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Item {
    width: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.width : 512
    height: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.height : 512
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
        zoomLevel: 14
    }
}
```

To which Qt Creator or the main program starting the widget answer that the `QtLocation` and `QtPositioning` modules are not installed.

I'm on Fedora 35 KDE and there is indeed nothing in the repositories providing `qml-modules-location`, and the only modules available seem to be part of the KDE desktop. I installed PySide6 through pip3.

I tried to install Qt from the .run file on their website. I picked the "Additional libraries" that sounded close to it (datavisualization, charts, etc.) and the Qt studio. It downloaded some 9 GB of bloat and I still don't have the modules after.

How can I fetch those modules and where should I put them on my OS ? Preferably in a way that doesn't involve downloading another 10 GB because I don't have an unlimited data plan. It feels like it should just be grabbing some header files from a git repo and yet it's a turducken of unwanted libs, and everything on Qt Linux points to Ubuntu installations with `apt-get`.